# Find XML files with specific values

Tags: linux, command-line, find, xml

I have a folder with ~10K XML files. Each of them looks like this:

```
...
<object>
<name>Cat</name>
</object>
<object>
<name>Cow</name>
</object>
...
```

The `name` includes person, cat, dog, cow, ... I want to pick out the only xml files with cat and/or dog. How can I do this?

Comment: I use an app called PowerGrep, but have to switch to windows tho

Comment: Should `<attribute><name>Cat</name></attribute>` also give a hit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the `Cat` or `Dog` values out of the `name` node in an XML document like yours, you may use `xmlstarlet` like this:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//object/name[text() = "Cat" or text() = "Dog"]' file.xml
```

This would generate the words `Cat` and `Dog` as output if they exist the document as the values of an `object` node's `name` child-node. This operation would be tricky to get right with `grep` in case there are other `name` nodes that are not child-nodes to `object` nodes, or if some `name` nodes have attributes etc.

Unfortunately, `xmlstarlet` does not exit with a non-zero exit status if it can't find anything in the XML input file, so we need to tack on a `grep` at the end of this to check whether we got any output at all (this will be used in the next step):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//object/name[text() = "Cat" or text() = "Dog"]' file.xml | grep '.'
```

We can then run this on all the 10k files though `find`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.xml' -exec sh -c '
    xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//object/name[text() = \"Cat\" or text() = \"Dog\"]" "$1" |
    grep -q "."' sh {} ';' -print
```

This would first find all regular files in or below the current directory whose names end with `.xml`.  For each such file, `xmlstarlet` is run to extract the `Cat` and `Dog` strings from the correct XML nodes, and `grep` is used to check whether `xmlstarlet` found anything. Running `grep` with its `-q` option makes the utility quiet, but it will exit with the appropriate exit status depending on whether it matched anything or not.

If `grep` found anything, `find` then prints the pathname of the file that contained the data.

Answer (score 1):

Following code is based on `GNU grep`

As you said , that all files are like this, so you can use grep

for Cat or Dog , use

```
grep -l '<name>\(Cat\|Dog\)</name>' *
```

for Cat and Dog both to be present, use

```
grep -l '<name>Cat</name>' * | xargs grep -l '<name>Dog</name>'
```

and if you want case-insensitive search , then add `-i` option to grep

`-l` - this option will print only filename having match

With normal regex, the characters `(`, `|` and `)` need to be escaped, so I have escaped them

Comment: Basic regular expression does not support alternation with `|` nor with `\|`. You have to either use `grep -E` to enable extended regular expressions or specify that you're using GNU `grep` (which does support alternation with `\|` in basic regular expressions).

Answer (score 0):

If you have *many* files consider the use of indexer tools like Beagle, Tracker, glimpse or similar.

Example:

```
$ glimpseindex -H .  MyDir
$ glimpse -l  -H .  'cat;dog'
```

to get the files containing cad and dog